# Set Noindex Follow to subdomains - robots.txt

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo, url-rewriting

I need to set noindex, follow to 3 subdomains. I found out that you can rewrite in .htaccess but how do you handle MUTIPLE subdomains? I don't see directories on the server for subdomains.

Here is what I found.

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.qrcodecity\.com$
   RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-dev.txt
  </IfModule>
```

This redirect robots.txt to robots-dev.txt for dev.qrcodecity.com

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can have rule like this for all the selected sub domains:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sub1|sub2|sub3)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots-sub.txt [L,NC]
```

Comment: So how would that work for 3 subdomains? How does it know which robots.txt maps to which domain? Can you post a sample? ex: sub1.sample.com, sub2, and sub3

Comment: As I wrote this rule will fire for **all sub domains**. You can place sub domain specific lines in `robots-sub.txt` file.

Comment: I do not want it to redirect all subdomains to robots-sub.txt. Just specific ones. I still wanna index some subdomain. Thanks

Comment: ok check updated answer, it will only rewrite 3 selected sub domains.

Comment: That looks more promising. I will mark as answer once confirmed. Thank you